# Limit proof with definition

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I need to prove the following:

$$
\lim_{{n\to\infty}} f(n) = \infty \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{{n\to\infty}} g(n) = \infty \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{{n\to\infty}} \frac{{\lg(f(n))}}{{\lg(g(n))}} = 0 \implies \lim_{{n\to\infty}} \frac{{f(n)}}{{g(n)}} = 0
$$

Here is my attempt to prove it:

We get from definition that:

$1. \lim_{{n\to\infty}} f(n) = \infty \quad \text{, for any } \epsilon > 0, \text{ there exists an } N_1 \text{ such that for all } n > N_1, f(n) > \epsilon$

$2. \lim_{{n\to\infty}} g(n) = \infty \quad \text{, for any } \epsilon > 0, \text{ there exists an } N_2 \text{ such that for all } n > N_2, g(n) > \epsilon$

$3.\lim_{{n\to\infty}} \frac{{\lg(f(n))}}{{\lg(g(n))}} = 0 \quad \text{, for any } \epsilon > 0, \text{ there exists an } N_3 \text{ such that for all } n > N_3, \left|\frac{{\lg(f(n))}}{{\lg(g(n))}} - 0\right| < \epsilon
$

Let $ \ N=max(N_1, N_2, N_3)$.

We get:

$-ε < \frac{{\lg(f(n))}}{{\lg(g(n))}} < ε ⇒$

$ -ε \lg(g(n)) < \lg(f(n)) < ε \lg(g(n)) ⇒$

$ \lg(g^{-ε}(n)) < \lg(f(n)) < \lg(g^{ε}(n)) ⇒$

$ g^{-ε}(n) < f(n) < g^{ε}(n) ⇒$

$ g^{-ε-1}(n) < \frac{{f(n)}}{{g(n)}} < g^{ε-1}(n)$

I want to say that for any $\Psi > 0$, there exists $N^*$ such that $0 < g^{-ε-1}(n) < \frac{{f(n)}}{{g(n)}} < g^{ε-1}(n) < 0$.

However, I can't prove it rigorously.

Comment: Let's denote $\frac{\lg f}{\lg g}=\frac{ f_1}{ g_1} \to 0$. Then we have $\frac{ f}{ g}=e^{f_1-g_1} =e^{g_1\left(\frac{ f_1}{ g_1}-1\right)} \sim e^{-g_1}\to0$

Comment: @zkutch I guess the full proof of monotonic transformation of limits has the same length as the direct for the OP problem.

Comment: @openspace. Possibly you are correct, you see, "same length" is little subjective estimation and for me is hard to agree or not agree, but I wrote also answer which is based on analogue estimation as comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on epsilon-delta way, then you are almost done. For simplicity let's assume $f,g\geqslant 0$ and consider last inequality
$$0 \leqslant \frac{{f(n)}}{{g(n)}} < g^{\varepsilon-1}(n)\quad (1)$$
As we can take $\varepsilon < 1$, then we fix it and consider limit for $n\to \infty$ in inequality $(1)$, which together with $g\to+\infty$ gives desired result.

Comment: Yes, then we can use the Squeeze theorem.
Thank you very much for the answer !!